# Sobolev space on $M \times [0,\infty)$, $M$ compact closed manifold

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, differential-geometry, manifolds, sobolev-spaces

Consider a  manifold of the form $M \times [0,\infty)$, where $M$ is a closed compact manifold without boundary. So $M \times [0,\infty)$ is a semi-infinite cylinder. I want to know information about Sobolev space on $M \times [0,\infty)$ and basic properties like trace theorems, Poincare type inequalities would be good too.

Is there any nice reference for such domains? I have been searching for days with no luck.